# When referring to a line integral what is the difference between the path and the parametrization of the path?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am struggling with this concept of the parametrization being path independent. It is true I asked a similar question before but I don't believe I did an adequate explanation.

Start with a line integral over the path $x = y^2$.  and we use the parametrization $x = t$ and $y = t^2$ over $0 < t < 1$.  ( The specific line integral is not given because it is not needed for the question.)  Now we can integrate with respect to t and come up with an area that represents work!  I am OK with this much.

Now let us change the parametrization to $x = sin(t)$ and $y = sin^2(t)$ over  $0 < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$. The work will be the same and the power will be the same.

My question:  what exactly is happening when we parameterize? Is there another function in the background that follows the same path in the same time?  I would like to get an intuitive sense of what parametrization does but is not affected by time since the power is the same. Thank you .

Comment: The parametrisation just gives you a way to tell you 'how fast' you travel over the path, but this isn't taken into account by the line integral itself.

Comment: thank you for fixing my messy text...i will learn to do that myself as I am able

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Area accumulated in different parametrizations]

This is an animation of the area below $y=x^2$ accumulated for $x = t$ and $x = \sin \frac{\pi t}{2}$ parametrizations as $t \in [0,1]$ varies. The integral computed is always this area, which is clearly independent of how fast the curve is traversed.

Comment: Sharkos ...this is exactly a beautiful idea how you presented this...i am amazed....would you be so kind now...I was told the power is the same with different parametrizations!  Does this mean the time that passes is the same when t goes from (0,1)   or from  0 to pi/2 ?  thank you so much

Comment: ...the reason I ask ...the first dot hits the top of the graph before the second dot so it almost seems like the 2nd parametrization has more power but  your beautiful demonstration shows they do equal work ..   this has been bothering me

Comment: The invariant idea is that the physical coordinate $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$. I rescaled your $\sin t \to \sin (\pi t/2)$ to make $t=0 \iff x=0$ and $t=1 \iff x = 1$ for convenience, so that I could compare the parametrizations directly. As a result, both dots actually hit the top point at the same $t$.

Comment: now I see......you are a good teacher....I can now move on with line integrals